# How to cache template in inclusion_tag

Tags: python, django, caching

I am trying to cache whole template in inclusion_tag but I've got problem with that.

Here is my code of inclusion_tag:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('accounts/helpers/user_info.html', takes_context=True)
def user_info(context, username, size=40):
    request = context['request']

    user = cache.get(username)

    if not user:
        user = User.objects.get(pk=username)
        print("cached")
        cache.set(
            username,
            user,
            settings.USER_LAST_ACTIVITY_TIMEOUT)

    return {'user': user, 'size': size}
```

and code of html template:

```
{% load static i18n humanize accounts cache %}
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}

{% cache 3600 user_info user.pk LANGUAGE_CODE size %}
<a class="user-info" href="{{ user.get_absolute_url }}">
    <div class="user-avatar-wrapper">
        <span class="online-status {{ user.online_status }}"></span>
        {% if size %}
            {% avatar user size class="avatar" id="user_avatar" %}
        {% else %}
            {% avatar user 40 class="avatar" id="user_avatar" %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <span>
        {{ user }}
        <small>{{ user.groups.all|join:", " }}</small>
    </span>
</a>
{% endcache %}
```

With this code I cache only user but I want to cache whole template in tag. Could you help me how to do it ? I've tried everything but I do not have idea how to deal with that.

THANK YOU

Comment: I am sorry to say this but you are really wasting your time. Here. These sort of trivial queries should not be cached. Caching template rendering does not speed them up either.

Comment: `User.objects.get(pk=username)` you are fetching a single item using a primary key this will be just as fast as getting it from memcached.

Comment: And if I want to.... How to do it ? Just let me know. Thank you :))

Answer (score 1):

I use simple tag:

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def user_info(context, username, size=40):
    tpl = cache.get(username)
    if not tpl:
        user = User.objects.get(pk=username)
        template = loader.get_template('app/user_info.html')
        tpl = template.render({'user': user, 'size': size})
        cache.set(username, tpl)
    return tpl
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice and effective solution given by @MikeS; thanks !

Nowadays, I would reformulate it as follows:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

@register.simple_tag
def user_info(context, username, size=40):
    html = cache.get(username)
    if not html:
        user = User.objects.get(pk=username)
        html = render_to_string(
            'app/user_info.html', {
                'user': user,
                'size': size,
            }
        )
        cache.set(username, html, timeout=60)
    return html
```